# Interference on 4k Samsung display connected to Macbook Pro 2016

Tags: macbook-pro, display, 4k

We have a Samsung 4K 28" UE590 display that's connected to a Macbook Pro 13" 2016 with an Apple USB-C to HDMI multiport adaptor. The whole setup is on a glass table.

We're getting huge amounts of static that interferes with the image on the display. When using the same setup on a normal wooden table, it works fine.

Except selling the glass table, what can be tried to avoid the static electricity problem?

thanks for the help

Comment: Try wrapping the cables in aluminum foil to shield it.  If you have anti-static bags, you can try wrapping them in that.

Comment: You could also try an [anti-static mat](https://amzn.to/39Mljx9) to put all the equipment on

Comment: Sounds like some kind of grounding problem. Have you tried swapping out the USB and HDMI cables. When you put it on the wooden table do you use different electric outlets?

Comment: @root - Why would it be a grounding problem if it exists on a glass table and not on a wood one? Both materials are insulators, but glass can develop a static charge.

Comment: Tks to all for comments. I will try the anti-static mat as that seems to be the most logical thing to do. thanks allan.

Comment: @Allan My point is not in the material of the table but the outlets. If you use different outlets on different tables the grounding of the outlet may be faulty.